# Таблица для графика цен

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных

Здравствуйте. Сейчас вот такая структура:

```
Товары | Пользователи | Товары_пользователей
```

В таблице `Товары_пользователей` хранится `id` товара, `id` пользователя, а так же цена, которую установил пользователь. А теперь собственно сам вопрос. Как правильно организовать структуру для таблицы архива цен, что бы потом вывести график цен. И как заносить туда цену? Каждый раз как появилась новая запись или обновилась запись в таблице `Товары_пользователей`? Как-то копировать цену с этой таблицы в таблицу с архивом цен? Как вообще это делается?

Comment: А зачем обновлять запись, теряя предыдущие данные и огребая геморрой с необходимостью создания архива? Не проще ли просто добавлять запись, а актуальность отслеживать по штампу времени (ну или переопределиться и ввести отдельное поле актуальности, если решение с выбором последней записи кажется слишком тяжёлым).

Comment: @Kromster done!

Comment: @Akina задача не в подерживании актуальной цены, а в том, что бы под товаром вывести график с ценами на данный товар (что бы показать как цена меняласьна данный товар в течении последнего года). А обновлять потому что цена на товарможет повысится.

Comment: Описанный мной подход позволяет решить именно эту задачу.

Comment: @Akina я с вами согласен. Но допустим, пользователь установил на товар с ид 5, цену 100 в 27.12.16.11.00.00. Но через неделю он поднял цену105. Получается он обновил эту запись, и цены 100 не осталось. По этому хочу все цены в отдельную таблицу

Comment: Если он поднял цену, то в таблице появляется ВТОРАЯ запись. С новой датой и новой ценой. А первая осталась без изменения. Всё. Нужна актуальная запись? _SELECT * FROM table WHERE id_good=5 ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1_. Нужны записи за год для графика? _SELECT * FROM table WHERE id_good=5 AND YEAR(date)=2016_

Comment: @Akina скорее всего он имеет в виду что то лог с ценами по датам (который вы перелагаете) он хочет вынести в отдельную таблицу и потом джойнить её.

Comment: @Alex_01 да вынесение в отдельную таблицу лога будет правильнее с точки зрения нормализации но вам всегда будет нужен дополнительный джоин. Так же возникает множество вопросов относительно того, каждый товар может быть только у одного пользователя или у вас список товаров и каждый пользователь может ставить на один и тот же товар свою стоимость?

Comment: @fens У меня каталог товаров, и каждый пользователь может ставить цену на любой товар только 1 цену. Один ко многим связь.

Comment: @Akina сделать такой запрос не проблема, но вам бы захотелось каждый раз добавлять новое предложение, заполнять поля и тд, или легче отредактировать старое объявление? Ответ очевиденя думаю

Comment: Если бы мне для ввода новой цены потребовалось заново всё вводить, я бы высказал своё громкое "ФЭ" разработчику системы. Это его забота - при изменении мной хотя бы одного параметра организовать не корректировку существующей записи, а вставку новой, где у незатронутых изменениями полей установлены те значения, которые были у предыдущей (а ещё лучше - именно корректируемой, ибо не факт, что я захочу источником данных использовать именно последнюю) записи.

Comment: @Alex_01 Akina правильно сказал вам необходимо не заменять цену а добавлять новую запись для каждого изменения цены конкретным пользователем, т.е. Ваша задаче как раз сделать "лог" журнал изменений цен на товары пользователями. А из него вы будете получать актуальные цены сортируя их по дате по убыванию. Если вы хотите оптимизировать выборки тогда будете хранить актуальную цену в своей основной таблице это называется денормализация ради оптимизации. Но при вставке вам нужно будет делать 2 запроса обновление в основной и добавление в таблицу лога.

Comment: Триггер вам в помощь

Comment: @Akina Я думаю мы друг друга не поняли. Пример того что я хочу сделать http://1k.by/

Comment: Akina, fens спасибо. Сделаю так, как вы сказали. rjhdby да,я и хотел использовать тригеры

Comment: Триггер использовать скорее всего не получится. Триггер по идее не должен разрешать изменение таблицы, на событие в которой он срабатывает - потому как есть потенция и зацикливания, и дедлока. MySQL - не разрешает гарантированно. Нужно логику изменения оформлять в виде хранимой процедуры. Ей передаются новые параметры, а она уже организует все необходимые телодвижения.